# In need of a map like solution for a project

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

EDIT: I am not asking you to write any code for me, I can write code just fine. I am however looking for a ready made solution built by someone else, something like an API, script etc that is GPL licensed or free to use.

I'm working on a project and I ran into a wall. I've created a database that holds "geo" data, i.e. coordinates in 2D form for a web game experiment. So the 2D coordinates in the database hold data as to what is on that "point in space".

Now, I need something to render that data into a "Google maps like" application that can pan the map and automatically load the data from the database (or pull it all at once and just render it as you pan the map).

My requirements are as follows:
- relatively simple to integrate
- cross browser compatible
- Preferably no Flash or Java
- JavaScript, PHP, HTML5, AJAX is a plus
- if it has any extra options, it would be nice if they could be regulated (i.e. turned on or off)
- image tiles are OK
- the ability to create a custom map made out of images is a **MUST**

I have looked around to see if there are any similar questions, and I have found some similar but after reading them I still haven't found anything decent.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: openmap is Java based, and doesn't match what I need at all.

Comment: @ToniKostelac "Give me the full code for [non-trivial project]" is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow. You can try to phrase it differently, so that it looks like a real question where the OP has shown some efforts in an attempt to solve a reasonably scoped problem.

Comment: @RobW I've made the edit on top of the post. It doesn't get any clearer now.

Comment: Perhaps "Is there a library to render custom spatial data in a map like interface?" Seems like a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try customising [leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/features.html) for this purpose. It's designed for more traditional maps. However, it might be possible to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I've took an extensive look at this API and it seams that with some modification i'll be able to make it work, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : [Geo](http://jquerygeo.com/) It uses JQuery.
 
You could add it's contents in a php file and populate the vertices from whatever data you stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider actually using the Google Maps API.

-you can load any custom overlays onto google maps and set the panning boundaries

-you could turn those 2D coordinates into lat/lng and place almost any object onto the map

-you can fully customize any buttons / controls

-Google Maps uses Javascript / HTML5 canvas

Here is an example to get started :

```
function initialize() {

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(someLat, someLng),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID

    }

    // attaches new map object to div
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            // SW coord
            new google.maps.LatLng(swLat, swLng),
            // NE coord
            new google.maps.LatLng(neLat, neLng));  

        overlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
        someUrlPath + '/map.gif',
        imageBounds,{map: map, clickable: false});
        overlay.setMap(map);


}// end of function initialize()
```

There are many options that are easy to implement and much functionality is done for you already.  Check out the documentation: [Google Maps Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Comment: This might just seam a good enough option, I'll have to check the documentation a bit to see if I can use it the way I intend to.